# In nested data (tibble nesting a named list), how could I mutate a new column in certain depth level based on existence of nested values

Tags: r, nested, nested-lists, tibble

When I have data that contains nested lists within, I want to mutate new columns in a certain level, conditioned by values existing in the deeper nested levels. Specifically, the object being nested is a named list, and I want to check against the *names* of that list to conclude whether info exists in the data or not.

---

### EDIT -- I replaced the data in my example

---

Although @Ronak's answer did answer my question with data given originally, I realized that I made a mistake and the toy data example didn't reflect correctly the structure of my data.
Below is data that reflects my situation correctly.

```r
library(tibble)

df_correct <-
  structure(
  list(
    var_name = c("age", "classes"),
    title = c("What is your age?",
              "what classes have you taken?"),
    class_descriptions = list(
      NULL,
      list(
        History = "History of Art",
        Chemistry = "Organic Chemistry",
        other = "Other Classes"
      )
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-2L),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame")
)

## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##   var_name title                        class_descriptions
##   <chr>    <chr>                        <list>            
## 1 age      What is your age?            <NULL>            
## 2 classes  what classes have you taken? <named list [3]>  <--- this list is what I need to check against

df_correct %>%
  unnest_wider(class_descriptions)

## # A tibble: 2 x 5
##                                    based on whether
##                                    "History" exists
##                                           ↓
##   var_name title                        History        Chemistry         other        
##   <chr>    <chr>                        <chr>          <chr>             <chr>        
## 1 age      What is your age?            NA             NA                NA           
## 2 classes  what classes have you taken? History of Art Organic Chemistry Other Classes
```

So given `df_correct`, and not necessarily by using `unnest_wider` (this was just to show the structure of the nested data), how can I mutate a new column in `df_correct` to account for whether "History" appears in `class_descriptions`?

#### Desired Output -- Updated

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  var_name title                        class_descriptions has_taken_history
  <chr>    <chr>                        <list>             <lgl>            
1 age      What is your age?            <NULL>             NA               
2 classes  what classes have you taken? <named list [3]>   TRUE
```

---

#### More about desired solution (rather than output)

My hope in posting this question is to find a method to add another column in `df_correct` for whether a string exists in *names* of named list `class_descriptions`. In other words, I'm looking for a solution that will require 2 inputs **only**:

1. What to search (in this example, the string `"History"`)
2. Where to search (in this example, the names of named list `class_descriptions` that is nested in `df_correct`).

If string found, populate `TRUE` in a new column in `df_correct`, otherwise, populate `FALSE`.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 2**

```
df_correct %>%
  mutate(has_taken_history = map_lgl(class_descriptions, 
                                     ~'History' %in% names(.x)))

# var_name title                        class_descriptions has_taken_history
#  <chr>    <chr>                        <list>             <lgl>            
#1 age      What is your age?            <NULL>             FALSE            
#2 classes  what classes have you taken? <named list [3]>   TRUE
```

---

**Edit 1**

For the edited data you can do :

```
library(tidyverse)

df_correct %>%
  mutate(class_descriptions1 = class_descriptions) %>%
  unnest_wider(class_descriptions) %>%
  mutate(across(History:other, ~ifelse(is.na(.), NA, TRUE))) %>%
  dplyr::select(var_name, title, class_descriptions = class_descriptions1, has_taken_history = History)

# var_name title                        class_descriptions has_taken_history
#  <chr>    <chr>                        <list>             <lgl>            
#1 age      What is your age?            <NULL>             NA               
#2 classes  what classes have you taken? <named list [3]>   TRUE
```

You can keep only the subjects that you need from the output.

---

**Original Answer**

You can use `map_lgl` to get a logical vector back :

```
df %>% 
  unnest_wider(info) %>%
  mutate(has_taken_history = map_lgl(classes_taken, ~"History" %in% .x), 
         has_taken_chemistry = map_lgl(classes_taken, ~"Chemistry" %in% .x))

#  student_name location      year_born classes_taken has_taken_history has_taken_chemistry
#  <chr>        <chr>             <dbl> <list>        <lgl>             <lgl>              
#1 John         San Francisco      2000 <chr [4]>     TRUE              FALSE              
#2 Sarah        Miami              2002 <chr [4]>     TRUE              TRUE
```

A more general solution for all the subjects would be to `unnest` the subjects and get data in wide format.

```
df %>% 
  unnest_wider(info) %>%
  unnest(classes_taken) %>%
  mutate(value = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = classes_taken, values_from = value, values_fill = FALSE)
  
#  student_name location      year_born Astronomy Cosmology History Robotics Chemistry Biology Zoology
#  <chr>        <chr>             <dbl> <lgl>     <lgl>     <lgl>   <lgl>    <lgl>     <lgl>   <lgl>  
#1 John         San Francisco      2000 TRUE      TRUE      TRUE    TRUE     FALSE     FALSE   FALSE  
#2 Sarah        Miami              2002 FALSE     FALSE     TRUE    FALSE    TRUE      TRUE    TRUE
```

---